# Counting the amount of sections in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want show the amount of sections of a tableView somewhere as a badge.

The first problem is that I get a outcome of 0.

I've declared a `int` in the TableViewController.h as `section`.

In the .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.section = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    NSLog(@"Number of sections in tableView are %d", self.section);
}
```

Why do I still get a 0 as outcome?
Is there somewhere in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` I need to count the amount of sections?

Thanks

---

**Update:**

In the tableView I set al the `scheduledLocalNotifications`.
I made a set of 2 notifications which are linked to each other.
*So 2 rows of `scheduledLocalNotifications` in each section.*

This is what I have in the tableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return (int)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]/2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    int rowIndex = (indexPath.section*2) + indexPath.row;

    // Get list of local notifications
    NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:rowIndex];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think you are setting the sections of tableview dynamically as per response from webservice. if this is the case then after parsing the data..You can store the sections count value you want to pass to numberOfSections delegate method in variable and can set it as badge..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find number of sections in any tableview after `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method call. So, initialize your variable in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method before return statement.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

I have several scheduledLocalNotification that a loaded into the table view. 

`return (int)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]/2;`

Could you give an example?